# Unable to Export 3M records data report

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have tabular report, dataset is returning 3M records and while running report getting Out of Memory exception. We are using SSRS 2012 and Microsoft jet base engine as well. Please suggest how can I export the report without issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS - OutOf MemoryException - is there a limit to the number of rows that can be displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542471/ssrs-outof-memoryexception-is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-rows-that-can-b)

Comment: This issue has been addressed and could have been found with Google, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542471/ssrs-outof-memoryexception-is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-rows-that-can-b) and [here](http://www.sqlserverdba.com.au/reportingservices-systemoutofmemoryexception/)